# attach Log4J source to project

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

I have project that uses `Log4j` logger. When I try to navigete to Log4J class `FileAppender` (CTRL+Click) I have page with button "Attach Souce". I have downloaded `Log4J` source from http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/log4j/trunk to C:\Projects\Log4J . File `FileAppender.java` is located in `C:\Projektai\Log4J\src\main\java\org\apache\log4j` directory. When I try attach source by passing this directory to `External location`, `External Folder` this doesn't help - I still can't see file content. How to attach source correctly?

Comment: Are you using gradle? It has a way to download and attach sources. Actually I have used it for intellij but there is a plugin for eclipse also.

Answer (score 0):

This happends, if eclipse or your ide not have the API or Source files installed for the lib you need. Install the API for Log4J into you IDE and this will not happend again.

Comment: e.g. the Java API : Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs -> Edit -> Javadoc URL.